# WebApi POST parameter always null

Tags: c#, json, breeze, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to set up a webapi method with which i can add an user to my database.
On the frontend i am using marionette backbone along with breezejs to savechanges to my webapi.

I have a entity on my backend for a user that looks as follows:

```cs
public class ApiUserEntity {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ApiPermission Permission { get; set; }
    public ApiUserRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

The 2 enums look like this:

```cs
public enum ApiUserRole {
    User,
    Staff,
    Admin,
    Master
}

public enum ApiPermission {
    Read,
    Write,
    ReadWrite,
    None
}
```

When i try to add (register) a user however the entity that is posted is always null.
[image: Posted entity is null]
But as you can see in the screenshot when i watch the posted value with:

```cs
base.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

I can see the posted json value only as a string.

```json
{"Id":-1,"CreatedAt":"1899-12-31T23:00:00","Username":"test","Password":"test","Email":"test@test.nl","Permission":"3","Role":"0"}
```

It seems it has something to do with the deserializing of the object.
I looked in fiddler to see if it was setting the correct Content-Type:

```json
--batch_7273 - bef2 - 5778
Content - Type: multipart / mixed; boundary = changeset_9a18 - de60 - f7a4

--changeset_9a18 - de60 - f7a4
Content - Type: application / http
Content - Transfer - Encoding: binary

POST / odata / ApiUsers HTTP/ 1.1
Content - ID: 1
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Accept: application / atomsvc + xml; q = 0.8, application / json; odata = fullmetadata; q = 0.7, application / json; q = 0.5, */*;q=0.1
Content-Type: application/json
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0

{"Id":-1,"CreatedAt":"1899-12-31T23:00:00","Username":"test","Password":"test","Email":"test@test.nl","Permission":"3","Role":"0"}
--changeset_9a18-de60-f7a4--

--batch_7273-bef2-5778--
```

And as you can see the content type is set to application/json for that batch item, yet my entity stays empty and it looks like webapi cannot convert the json to my apiuserentity object.

EDIT my route registration is as follows:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion"); // origins, headers, methods
    config.EnableCors(cors);

    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityHelpers.GetConfiguredContainer());

    // enable elmah
    config.Services.Add(typeof (IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<ApiUserEntity>("ApiUsers");
    builder.EntitySet<DomainEntity>("Domains");
    builder.EntitySet<RouteEntity>("Routes");
    builder.EntitySet<ModuleEntity>("Modules");

    config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "odata",
        routePrefix: "odata",
        model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
        batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
        );
}
```

EDIT2:
I have traced the exceptions when the webapi action was being hit and found this:

```
 iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method = POST, Url = http://localhost:22594/odata/ApiUsers, Message='http://localhost:22594/odata/ApiUsers'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'ApiUsers', Operation = DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'WebAPI.Controllers.ApiUsersController', Operation = DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'WebAPI.Controllers.ApiUsersController', Operation = HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Selected action 'Post(ApiUserEntity apiUserEntity)'', Operation = ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Selected action 'Post(ApiUserEntity apiUserEntity)'', Operation = ODataActionSelector.SelectAction
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation = ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation = ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation = ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation = ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation = ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation = ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Will use new 'ODataMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation = ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Will use same 'FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation = FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message = 'Will use same 'JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter' formatter', Operation = JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Operation = ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync, Exception = System.NotImplementedException: the method or operation is not implemented

at System.Web.HttpContextBase.get_Response()
at System.Web.UI.Util.GetUrlWithApplicationPath(HttpContextBase context, String url)
at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.NormalizeVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, String name, RouteValueDictionary values)
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HostedHttpRouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(HttpRequestMessage request, String name, IDictionary`2 values)
at System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper.GetVirtualPath(HttpRequestMessage request, String routeName, IDictionary`2 routeValues)
at System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper.Route(String routeName, IDictionary`2 routeValues)
at System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper.Link(String routeName, IDictionary`2 routeValues)
at System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions.UrlHelperExtensions.CreateODataLink(UrlHelper urlHelper, String routeName, IODataPathHandler pathHandler, IList`1 segments)
at System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions.UrlHelperExtensions.CreateODataLink(UrlHelper urlHelper, IList`1 segments)
at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetBaseAddress(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
```

EDIT3: I have changed my controller type to apicontroller instead of odatacontroller and now it suddenly works. I would like to use odatacontroller

Comment: what do you get in `apiUserEntity`? Is it `null`?

Comment: Yes `apiUserEntity` is `null`

Comment: I have updated the screenshot so that it is more clear.

Comment: works fine for me, can you show some more code, the route registration and is there any enum?

Comment: Show the content of `ApiPermission` and `ApiUserRole`.

Comment: I have changed my question to include my routeconfiguration and enums. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Are you using `EntityFramework`?In that case verify the property name of the `COntext` class.

Comment: Why do you want to use odatacontroller?

Comment: Inherit from ApiController instead, to support odata queries, just add the [Queryable]-attribute to the actions.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

1. Date field is being deserialized properly.
2. Try assigning your Enums int values, and pass the JSON value as an int instead of a string.
3. Should you be passing a -1 for your Id?  Leave this field null, if its populated by the DB, let it be populated by the DB.

Comment: Probably better as a comment since this provides items to check instead of a solution to the issue.